# Why typescript complains that XXX is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint X?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, typescript-generics

My code is this:

```
export interface TreeItem {
  id: string;
  children: this[];
  collapsed?: boolean;
}

const createTreeItem = <T extends TreeItem>(): T => {
  return {
    id: 'root',
    children: []
  }
}
```

But I get an error on the return type of `createTreeItem` which is the following:

> `TS2322`: Type '`{ id: string; children: never[]; }`' is not assignable to
> type '`T`'.   '`{ id: string; children: never[]; }`' is assignable to the
> constraint of type '`T`', but '`T`' could be instantiated with a different
> subtype of constraint '`TreeItem`'.

I have absolutely no idea what does this mean.

Any help ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So let's say you call your function as follows:

```js
let node = createTreeItem<TreeItem>()
```

All good, right? The return type `T` is `TreeItem`, and the object your generic function is hardcoded to return does in fact have a type that qualifies it as a `TreeItem`:

```
{ id: string; children: never[]; }
```

But the point of giving your function a type parameter is to allow it to be called with other types of `T`, as long as they extend `TreeItem`. So the following should be a legal call:

```
export interface BidiTreeItem {
  id: string;
  children: this[];
  parent: this;
  collapsed?: boolean;
}

let node = createTreeItem<BidiTreeItem>()
```

The call is legal, since `BidiTreeItem` satisfies the constraint `T extends TreeItem`. The return type of this call, as declared in your function definition, is `BidiTreeItem`, but what your function returns is NOT a `BidiTreeItem`.

If you reread the error message again but with the above example in mind, it will now make sense to you. But just in case, below I will translate each piece of the error message. Note that the first sentence is the conclusion, so it will go last in this table:

| this part of the error message... | means this (using above example)... |
| --- | --- |
| `'{ id: string; children: never[]; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T'` | `'{ id: string; children: never[]; }'` is consistent with the constraint `T extends TreeItem` |
| `but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TreeItem'.` | but `T` could be instantiated with a different subtype of `TreeItem`, for example `BidiTreeItem`. |
|  |  |
| `TS2322: Type '{ id: string; children: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.` | The object your function is returning is not guaranteed to be assignable to type `T`, because `T` could be some other subtype such as `BidiTreeItem` . |

Comment: Nice example. [Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_constraints) I  have written an article about it

Comment: @captain-yossarian, nice!  BTW, what do you think about me asking the Typescript folks to make a better worded error message? I was thinking something along the lines of: *"You've fallen for one of the two classic blunders! The first being never set `noImplicitAny: false`, but only slightly lesser known: never go against a parametrized return type constraint when type safety is on the line! HAHAHAHAHAHAHA \*program dies\*"*

Comment: I'm not very well aware about error message strategy they are using. Probably worth creating some document with explanation of every error code. For instance: `TS2322 - means that .....`

Comment: you can remove :) And I will remove mine

Comment: So If a type is passed to T that defines additional fields that are required, which are not there in the hardcoded return, then it will fail. Did I get that right?

Comment: @sezanzeb: If Typescript allowed you to do that, yes, that would be a Typescript failure. The error message is Typescript telling you you are doing something illogical.

Comment: I have finally understood this error, thanks @Inigo! Now I'm cursed on "how to properly fix this". Maybe `createTreeItem<T extends X>(makeT: (input: unknown) => T): T`?

Comment: @WesSouza There is no universal way to fix the general case. It all depends on the specifics of your case! In the question's case, there CANNOT be a solution. How can you hardcode a return value (which has a specific type) for a function with a generic return type? It's not logical!

Comment: @Inigo see the answer I added below. It does solve both this case and the problem I was having in my codebase.

Answer (score -4):

You can add "`as T` after the return" :

```
  const createTreeItem = <T extends TreeItem>(): T => ({
      id: 'root',
      children: []
  } as T);
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, and only hides the problem. If you did this, then there would be no reason to use generics in the first place!

Comment: T is already a generic type that extends TreeItems so this is not just hiding the problem. Typescript just needs to know what type your object ison return because it is not infered because you use return while creating an object direclty with {} and as you write on your code T should be the type of the result of the function.

Comment: See my answer. Your "fix" undermines the point of declaring the return type to be `T`. If the actual return type disregards the type parameter `T`, then it is lying. Your fix hides this lie. If the idea is that the compiled Javascript doesn't need to know about the lie, then why bother even having a generic parameter T at all? You would just declare this function as such (`createTreeItem = (): { id: string; children: never[]; }`)