# Create a TypeScript mixin which both constrains and knows about what type it is mixed into

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-mixins

I'm trying to share some model objects between the client and server code (all in TypeScript).  I would like to create the "shared" model so that it doesn't know anything about where it's being used, and then provide a mixin to add the server functionality (e.g., fetch from a database) on the server side, and a different mixin to provide the client functionality (e.g., fetch from a RESTful API) on the client.

Here's a simplified version of what I have so far (here's a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weX6gW), too):

```
// generic declaration of a constructor type to make things easier later on
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

// this is the base model class which can be used by client or server code
class Model extends Object {
    public id: number = 1;
}

// this is a specific model subclass, also usable on client or server
class Widget extends Model {
    public length: number = 10;
}

// this class is only used on the server, but needs to know the type of model being acted upon
class ServerHelper<T> {
    public async insert(model: T): Promise<T> { /* do the insert */ return Promise.resolve(model); }
}

// this is the public interface for the server-side mixin
interface ServerModel<M extends Model> {
    helper: ServerHelper<M>;
}

// this is the server-side mixin which 
function ServerModel<B extends Constructor<Model>>(Base: B): B & Constructor<ServerModel<InstanceType<B>>> {
    type M = InstanceType<B>;

    const result = class BaseWithServerModel extends Base {
        public helper: ServerHelper<M> = new ServerHelper<M>();

        public async insert(): Promise<this> {
            return await this.helper.insert(this);
        }
    };

    return result;
}

class SpecialWidget extends ServerModel(Widget) {
    // this class needs this.helper to be a `Helper<Widget>`
}
```

I've been trying to adapt [the constrained mixin example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#constrained-mixins), but I can't find any formulation which gives me access to the type being mixed into (i.e., `Widget` in my example) so that it can be passed along to other generic types.

Instead, I get a bunch of error like this one on the `return result;` line:

```
'BaseWithServerModel' is assignable to the constraint of type 'M', but 'M' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Model'.
```

I've spent hours digging around on the web and tinkering with various incantations on my own, but I've got nothing.  Any suggestions on how I should declare my mixin so that I get access to `M`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjZD7w) meet your needs?  I've found the mixin support in TS to be somewhat alchemical; the normal way to do this seems to be where the function is generic in the constructor type and not the instance type.  If that works for you I could maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks!  I know I played with using `InstanceType` at one point, and I ran into a roadblock with it in my real codebase.  I don't remember what the roadblock was, though.  Let me try it again and get back to you.

Comment: It's close, but I still get an error I can't figure out what to do with.  Here's a [more realistic example](https://tsplay.dev/weX6gW).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70391664/why-typescript-complains-that-xxx-is-assignable-to-the-constraint-of-type-t-b?rq=1) seems relevant... I'm creeping up on maybe understanding this...

Comment: Yeah, polymorphic `this` and generic conditional types like `InstanceType<B>` are hard to deal with.  Personally if I were you I'd just use assertions where necessary like `this as M`, and stay away from polymorphic `this` types unless they are necessary.  Perhaps as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WGP2ow).  Not sure if this is good enough for your needs.

Comment: I *do* need to return a `Promise<this>`, but with a tiny tweak, I think [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/WYkLzN) does what I need.  Thank you very much!  If you want to write up a quick answer, I'd be very happy to give you the credit.  :-)

Comment: I don't know if you've ever *seen* my answers, but "quick" is apparently not my modus operandi. I'll write up something when I get a chance, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243920/discussion-between-andrew-miner-and-jcalz).

Comment: Hmm, your question still has vestiges of the old version where you mention "Class 'BaseWithServerModel' incorrectly extends base class 'M'." which is no longer happening; could you edit that?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot reason very well about the behavior of types that depend on an unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) like `B` inside the body of `ServerModel`.  Especially when the type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype).  So unfortunately code like the following just results in an error:

```
function foo<T extends new () => object>(ctor: T) {
    const oops: InstanceType<T> = new ctor(); // error
}
```

The knows that `new ctor()` is an `object`, but it doesn't realize that it must be an `InstanceType<T>`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#37705](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37705) for a related issue.

If you want this to compile you will need to use something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know it's correct even though it doesn't:

```
function foo2<T extends new () => object>(ctor: T) {
    const oops = new ctor() as InstanceType<T>; // okay
}
```

So you'll need something like this in your code:

```
this.helper.insert(this as M)
```

---

A similar limitation is present with [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types).  Inside the body of a class, the `this` type is essentially a generic type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the type of the current class.  So the compiler will not always be sure whether some value is assignable to `this`.

In your case,

```
    public async insert(): Promise<this> {
        return await this.helper.insert(this as M);
    }
```

the compiler is technically correct to complain.  The return type of `insert()` should be a `Promise<this>` where `this` is the type of whatever subclass of `BaseWithServerModel` is being used.  But `this.helper.insert()` returns only `Promise<M>`.  And is is possible that `this` will be a proper subclass of `M`.

If you don't care about such a possibility because it's unlikely, you can use another type assertion:

```
    public async insert(): Promise<this> {
        return await this.helper.insert(this as M) as this;
    }
```

This compiles with no errors and lets you move on with your life.  Maybe there are some better and more type safe solutions, but it might not be worth it.

In your comment you mentioned

```
    public async insert2(): Promise<this> {
        await this.helper.insert(this as M);
        return this;
    }
```

which may work as well.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHMFMDtIJwJYGNQBNJIDYEM7YC4ID20oRAZqNqEiQM75wCuS+Rco+AngA6SdFQAW2wBrfvgAWCaODqhI2Ognigc+VSQCwAKG59QAYXqMWbOAB4AKgD5QAXlCwA7qAAUAOi+45ALirQXADaALoAlA52VgDcurrkTNCsxKTkRETWCgAeGtCo8i7uEfZ2RABGAFYY+DZurOz+VhEA3rqg7TQmZEQ8dP4AktAM2EmQVryQ1naOhfVwbmHRoCAKcHDsugC+cToJSYQkoGlEAEyZkDkw+U6QrguRZJXVtXONLW0dtEP43b0ON645vclKBBsNRuM+FMlisiKJsFwtjtdCspAh5OjOJJ+GUlPwhER0JgaDg6PJnNIkJIaCNQGV+Ew6JBUHSuCSVNAfuxQEy4AA3VS0dC6LBKeQAWUJkGJF1y1wA8k9WKBWjoOqAeEwyphkKAEKh-NAmEJ6RxHABGWI6bY6FFgNEY+TUOh8JAIci6glEnla0VkgA0VEwdEEjOw2v4hywHK5HF5ArgItJ8gA6vqoD9ZVcJVLiar1ZrtbrMDBwFJDcbTf9zQAGK02u1YzF+x1kaCYNmM5ltrH8ePwQNlJg-WDM+RsUCiaBEVxSCQTMiUL3SumQGTgKisbtMHjaHQt0AAZXgCYAEtK+JZbCqPu1CzqUEouEk9UN4Pg3MvMG9-AAFdZCOikzXs0ywAFRoIIc6vryPxgWAcCQPgTBwKQ-5EIBTIeIhIaYAKn65osoA2g2OiotIrbQfeuoyBocDkNgSD8GkHDQf2cAALTKOgwgIFkMi6LR8AMUxR4nvAkpEhY4rZHKOZEnY+YdNimCXv4x78vA56qfA0k2Fa6oyLBCx-gBQEWA6+lIrauyJMkhwaQmknShYABCsnZkYJjMHM0m5jYtSuXi-iue8aodPo-AyY4YL4CMTGQpMrk2LenTfKAOFMJgPyOAeQVMmmUiORJuYeXk8j5fwSnqneWoPqAKlqWJmlwNpl56f8hTFa1F66eKtSLKlBZ1bqT4vkZ74maA6GYZMlk3uFNU1YhyGoVQzjYAgPwOh4jXwB4E1wB+DpUBKEQgg6BlLcRQ0dNRj50M+KCHfgJxTTN5nzdV13tNgG1bU2dC7b1cAHW+R1uCdILioNi0-RlSEoaQl23e0NrqpsVqpStSMI3QWX4PWOwHoeroINgmBpqgGZldc3XOZgbhUxmYXquRzbJjcY6A8DOmsYI9JUKAAAGbW6czSE2MLqXHPc33qjte2JnDJFAA)